# JavaScript Equivalent of WordPress do_action and apply_filters Functions

Tags: javascript, wordpress, callback

Is there a JavaScript library that provides functionality that is equivalent to WordPress' `do_action` and `apply_filters` functions?

I have a need to process zero or more callback functions from unknown sources that will be called at specific, named, processing points. I think the `do_actions` functionality can be handled through DOM events, but `apply_filters` must return data back to the caller and I am not aware of any native JavaScript mechanism to accomplish this.

Effectively, I need to be able to:

1. Register one or more callback functions to be called at a specific process point based on a process hook name. Something like: `register_filter( 'hook-get-controls', my_get_controls_callback );`
2. When the 'hook-get-controls' process point is reached, call all registered filters callback function with something like: `controls = filter_callback_function( controls, hook_level_parameters );`

Each filter may alter the value (first parameter) as they see fit and then return the altered value to the filter's caller.

I know I can build this but am wondering if there is a library already built (or maybe native JavaScript that I am not aware of).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the block editor? If so, yes there are both actions and filters: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-hooks/

Comment: Otherwise there's just regular JavaScript events

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think you nailed it with https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-hooks. If this were an answer instead of a comment, it would be my Accepted answer. :)

Comment: I'm fine with you writing up an answer, maybe with some sample code if at all possible? Even if totally valid, some people see a link-only (or even a mostly link-only) answer as wrong.